# How to configure a subdomain to open a subpage on the main domain with nginx?

Tags: url, nginx, subdomain

So I have a domain example.com and a subdomain sub.example.com.

I would like to configure my Nginx virtual host to open the root site when a user uses the domain example.com but when a user uses sub.example.com the server should serve example.com/sub. The main problem I'm having is the URL changing. I do not want to simply redirect, instead, the URL should stay the same.

So basically you can open the same page by visiting example.com/sub or sub.example.com but the URL should always be sub.example.com.

Answer (score 0):

In your nginx configuration file for `sub.example.com`, under `location /`,
You can `proxy-pass` to the page you want to show. In this case `example.com/sub`.
But if you have more links on `example.com/sub` page, your routing would need some tweaks. Else, it should work fine.